# Exposé in 10.6: When exposing "Application Windows", how do you show only the windows in the current space?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-spaces, expose

In Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard, If you activate the "Application Windows" Exposé function, it will show all of that applications windows, whether they're in the current Space or not. Is there a way to have the "Application Windows" Exposé function show only those application windows that are in the current Space?

I have perhaps a dozen TextMate windows open across multiple spaces, and it's difficult to find the one I'm looking for if all of them are shown instead of just the ones in the current space.

This is a change from Leopard 10.5. Is there a way to reactivate the old behavior?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Try clicking on a window in a different space. I'm going to report it.

Comment: When I click a window in a different space, it activates the other space.

Comment: Really? When I click a window in a different space, the window becomes active but the space remains the same.

Comment: related discussion at Apple: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2132432&tstart=0

Comment: You'll want Lion for that.

Comment: I have the same problem in Lion. Once I get around to upgrading to Mountain Lion [this](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57485222-263/restore-classic-expose-behavior-in-mountain-lion/) will help a little, although it isn't quite what I want. Have you found a solution to that works for you yet, John?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution!

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dock wvous-show-windows-in-other-spaces -bool FALSE
$ killall Dock
```

(Via [MacOSXHints](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090930071112438) via the support discussion)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Lion.

Comment: Doesn't work on El Capitan too.