# Exposé in 10.7: When exposing “Application Windows”, how do you show only the windows in the current space?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-spaces, expose

This is basically the same question as [Exposé in 10.6: When exposing "Application Windows", how do you show only the windows in the current space?](https://superuser.com/questions/38460/expose-in-10-6-when-exposing-application-windows-how-do-you-show-only-the-win), but with 10.7 Lion.

In Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, If you activate the "Application Windows" Exposé function, it will show all of that applications windows, whether they're in the current Space or not. Is there a way to have the "Application Windows" Exposé function show only those application windows that are in the current Space?

I have perhaps a dozen TextMate windows open across multiple spaces, and it's difficult to find the one I'm looking for if all of them are shown instead of just the ones in the current space.

This is a change from Leopard 10.5. There was a fix for 10.6, but it doesn't work in 10.7. Is there a way to reactivate the old behavior?

Comment: @flow Please explain your requirements in more detail. What do you expect on an answer for it to receive your bounty?

Comment: none of the answers below respond to the current question

Answer (score 4):

You can activate "application windows" from within mission control to see just the windows for that application that are within the current space. With a magic mouse, hover over the application you're interested in and give a single finger swipe up. I'm not sure what the gesture is for a trackpad. It's not the ideal (read tiled) applications window you normally get but at least it's something.

Bonus Tip: when in mission control you can type the name of the window to highlight it, you can also quick look into it via the spacebar.

Comment: +1 for use mission control, which I think is Apple's "All in one" solution

Comment: For those without a magic mouse, the scroll wheel works too.

Comment: For those with a Magic Trackpad I believe the gesture is a two finger swipe down while hovering over the group of windows.

Comment: I activated "application windows" from within mission control and I have "Finder" windows in two different spaces. When I do what you mention, I get finder windows from both spaces

Comment: What I then doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I have a better solution that I just stumbled upon by accident.

Press Command-Tab to bring up the Application Switcher. Choose the app you want to expose, and leaving Command depressed, hit 1. (Another way to think about it: press and hold Command, then type Tab and 1 in succession).

This will reveal all the open Windows for that application. Once you're in this mode you can let go of Command, then hit Tab to move forward to the next app, or move backwards using Shift-Tab or Tilde (~).

From here you can also use the arrow keys to highlight your window, then hit Enter to enlarge it.

You're welcome. :)
Apple, why did you make this useful feature so obscure?

Comment: This is an obscure way of getting to the feature under discussion: App-Expose.  The problem is that windows from the same application but in different spaces are all displayed, instead of only windows from the current space.

Answer (score -1):

Control + Down Arrow in Mavericks does App-Expose.

Now only wish there was a single monitor expose.. I am usually focused on one monitor at a time so expose on multiple monitors at the same time is overkill.